# JSP enctype="multipart/form-data" get null data

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

When I use enctype=“multipart/form-data” for upload and input many data get null, if delete enctype=“multipart/form-data” it can get data but upload null. My code html

```
<form action="createvendor" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div>
        <label> <input placeholder="Username:" type="text"
                       name="username" tabindex="1" >
        </label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label> <input placeholder="Password" type="password"
                       name="password" tabindex="2" >
        </label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label> <input placeholder="Firstname:" type="text"
                       name="firstname" tabindex="3" >
        </label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label> <input placeholder="Lastname:" type="text"
                       name="lastname" tabindex="4" >
        </label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label> <input placeholder="ID card:" type="text"
                       name="personalID" tabindex="5" maxlength="13"
                       onKeyUp="if(isNaN(this.value)){ alert('กรุณากรอกตัวเลข 13 หลักเท่านั้น'); this.value='';}"
                >
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="registration_form">
        <div style="position: relative;">
            <a class='btn btn-primary'> Choose your ID card picture <input
                    required class="form-control" type="file"
                    style='position: absolute; z-index: 2; top: 0; left: 0; filter: alpha(opacity = 0); -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)"; opacity: 0; background-color: transparent; color: transparent;'
                    name="picturePersonalID"
                    onchange='$("#upload-file-info").html($(this).val());'>
            </a>&nbsp; <span class='label label-info' id="upload-file-info"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

I want to upload and input many data and send data to servlet.

Comment: did you solve your problem or still you have it?

Answer (score 0):

If you need  in order to upload a file by  which you intend to add later on, then you should put @MultipartConfig annotation on your servlet, so that request.getParameter() will work and that all uploaded files can be retrieved by request.getPart().`@MultipartConfig(maxFileSize = 1073741824)`

Answer (score -1):

@MultipartConfig(maxFileSize = 1073741824) put this annotation on method